# MenuItemDataBound in site.master

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, menu, menuitem, master-pages

I'm going crazy trying to manipulate the Menu in my site.master.  I've got the following Menu in my site.master:

```
    <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal"> 
        <Items> 
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Welcome" Value="0" NavigateUrl="Default.aspx"></asp:MenuItem> 
            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="Times.aspx" Text="Timesheets" Value="1"></asp:MenuItem> 
            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="View.aspx" Text="View Staff" Value="2"/> 
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Add Staff" Value="2" NavigateUrl="Add.aspx"></asp:MenuItem> 
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Options" Value="3"> 
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Jobs" Value="3" NavigateUrl="Jobx.aspx"></asp:MenuItem> 
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Courses" Value="3" NavigateUrl="Modx.aspx"></asp:MenuItem> 
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Increases" Value="3" NavigateUrl="Incx.aspx"></asp:MenuItem> 
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="User.aspx" Text="Users" Value="3"></asp:MenuItem> 
            </asp:MenuItem> 
        </Items> 
    </asp:Menu>
```

And for sake of simplicity, I've added and adjusted the following [this msdn VB example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menu.menuitemdatabound.aspx) to my site.master vb file:

```
Partial Class Site
Inherits System.Web.UI.MasterPage 

Public Sub NavigationMenu_MenuItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.MenuEventArgs) Handles NavigationMenu.MenuItemDataBound 

    e.Item.Text = "Custom Text" 

End Sub 
End Class
```

My understanding is that all of the items within my menu should subsequently have the text "Custom Text", but it just isn't happening. Am I missing something painfully obvious?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no data source attached to this menu so the menuitemdatabound is never executed.

If you wanted to manipulate the items you could do this in the page_load.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    For Each item As MenuItem In NavigationMenu.Items
        item.Text = "CUSTOM"
    Next
End Sub
```